# Store a 2D array into an array?

Tags: java, arrays

So I have this method here. This is creating a 2D array.

```
public static int[][] createCacheArray(int cacheSize, int blockSize, int[] memory, int i) {

    //Create multi-dimension array for cache.

    int [][] cache = new int [cacheSize/blockSize][blockSize];

    for (int column = 0; column < blockSize; column++) {
      for (int row = 0; row < cache.length; row++) {
           cache[row][column] = memory[i];
           i++;
      } 
    }

    return cache;

}
```

I would like to store the created Cache 2D array into a 1D array because I will be making multiple 2D cache arrays using this same method and I would like to organize them.

Basically I want to go to array [number] where a Cache 2D array is located and then read the contents of that cache 2D array. If there is another method I would gladly appreciate it.

The other way of doing it is this:

```html
cache = createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 0));
cache1 = createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 1));
cache2 = createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 2));
cache3 = createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 3));
```

Here, cache is 2D array, cache1 is a 2D array, cache 2 is a 2D array and so on, but this is inconvenient. The reason why im asking is because these are fixed 64x16 2D arrays. If an array gets filled, then I have to make another 2D array with the same size. Instead of making multiple variables, I was thinking it was possible to somehow store these onto an array. Like the 2D arrays are books and the 1D array is the shelf.

==================

The 2D arrays have numbers inside them.

After doing AndersonVieira's suggestion, all of my 2D arrays are stored into the ArrayList. This is perfect.

All I want to do now is search for a specific number in all of those 2D arrays inside the ArrayList. But I don't know what code to write to do this. I'm still a beginner in Java.

Comment: How would you want to add it to a 1D array ? What would be a given 2D array and it expected 1D array ?

Comment: Have you considered using a 3d array? Or a `Map`?

Comment: I updated my post. Basically the method makes a 2D array. But the only way I know to store each 2D array is by making multiple variables. I was thinking if it is possible to organize this in some way.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The 2D arrays that i'm making are fixed. I can only make a 64x16 2D array, so after this is filled up with numbers, I need to make another 2D 64x16 arrays and so on until all the numbers are placed into the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a `List<int[][]>` and store your caches in there:

```
List<int[][]> caches = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < numCaches; i++) {
    caches.add(createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * i)));
}
```

Then, you could access the caches by doing:

```
int[][] cache = caches.get(j);
```

Where `j` is the index of the desired element in the `caches` list.

Or, if you need to do something to each stored cache, you could iterate on the list:

```
for (int[][] cache : caches) {
    doSomething(cache);
}
```

This would probably be easier to work with than using a 3D array.

**Edit:**

To check if a 2-dimensional array contains an element, you need to loop through all the positions comparing the position value to the desired value:

```
static boolean contains(int element, int[][] cache) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cache.length; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < cache[i].length; j++) {
            if (cache[i][j] == element) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then you could create a method that returns the first cache that contains the specified element, or `null` otherwise:

```
static int[][] cacheContaining(int element, List<int[][]> caches) {
    for (int[][] cache : caches) {
        if (contains(element, cache)) {
            return cache;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this without adding "cache1", "cache2"..etc? I would like to do this in a for loop.

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < numCaches; i++) { caches.add(createCacheArray(...)); }`

Comment: This method is perfect, just one more question. Once the list has been created, there is a number that I need to find from all of these 2D array list created. How would I do this now that the 2D arrays are organized into an arraylist?

Comment: @user3311682 Do you need to search each cache to see if they contain a certain number? Assuming you have a function that does this to a single cache, you can iterate on the list and apply this function to each stored cache. I updated the answer with an example using a method called `doSomething()`.

Comment: @AndersonVieira I kind of need help. Using the example above, it stored all of the 2D arrays to the ArrayList. Suppose that I want to find a number and its stored in of the 2D arrays. Im guessing a for loop can help but I'm not sure how to find a specific value. I just need this part and I can mark this as solved.

Comment: @user3311682 Did you try using a `for` loop as I did in the example with the `doSomething()` method?

Comment: @AndersonVieira What's the method to read for an integer in this case?

Comment: @user3311682 I am not sure I understand. Could you update your question with a more detailed explanation and an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 3d array like,

```
int[][][] cache = {
    createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 0)),
    createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 1)),
    createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 2)),
    createCacheArray(cacheSize, blockSize, memory, (cacheSize * 3))
};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cache);
```